# Error Handling with Index Match function in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA and I have implemented an index/match function that returns data correctly.
The only thing that needs to be corrected is about how this code handles the values that are not matched. In this case values that don't have a match return the #N/A error while I would like to return simply zero.

```
  Sub IndexMatch()

Dim destinationWs As Worksheet, dataWs As Worksheet
Dim destinationLastRow As Long, dataLastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim IndexRng As Range, IndexRng2 As Range, MatchRng As Range

Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination")
Set dataWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Population")

destinationLastRow = destinationWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
dataLastRow = dataWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Set IndexRng = dataWs.Range("B2:B" & dataLastRow)
Set MatchRng = dataWs.Range("A2:A" & dataLastRow)


For x = 2 To destinationLastRow

On Error Resume Next
    
a = Application.Match(destinationWs.Range("A" & x).Value, MatchRng, 0)

If IsError(a) Then
    b = 0
Else
    b = Application.Index(IndexRng, a)
End If
       
'destinationWs.Range("C" & x).Value = Application.Index( _
'IndexRng, Application.Match(destinationWs.Range("A" & x).Value, MatchRng, 0))

On Error GoTo 0

Next x
    
    End Sub
```

How can I translate that in the above code?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the application version Match, like so **where b would be your destination range.**

```
a = Application.Match("XYZ", Range("F1:F100"), 0)

If IsError(a) Then
    b = 0
Else
    b = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("F1:F100"), a)
End If
```

Comment: I will post the full code because I tried your solution but it doesn't return any result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code:

```
Sub IndexMatch()

Dim destinationWs As Worksheet, dataWs As Worksheet
Dim destinationLastRow As Long, dataLastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim IndexRng As Range, IndexRng2 As Range, MatchRng As Range

Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination")
Set dataWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Population")

destinationLastRow = destinationWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
dataLastRow = dataWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Set IndexRng = dataWs.Range("B2:B" & dataLastRow)
Set MatchRng = dataWs.Range("A2:A" & dataLastRow)


For x = 2 To destinationLastRow

On Error Resume Next
    
a = Application.Match(destinationWs.Range("A" & x).Value, MatchRng, 0)

If IsError(a) Then
    b = 0
Else
    b = Application.Index(IndexRng, a)
End If
       
'destinationWs.Range("C" & x).Value = Application.Index( _
'IndexRng, Application.Match(destinationWs.Range("A" & x).Value, MatchRng, 0))

On Error GoTo 0

Next x
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Change `b = 0` to `destinationWs.Range("C" & x).Value = 0`. Change `b = Application.Index(IndexRng, a)` to `destinationWs.Range("C" & x).Value = Application.Index(IndexRng, a)`. You actually have to write to the sheet. Also ... please edit your question instead of posting in the answer space.